# Могу ли я обратиться к ресурсу, как к внешнему файлу?

Tags: c++, файловая-система, ресурсы

Есть файл ресурсов, допустим `picture PNG picture.png`.

Я его преобразую в `.res` командой `windres res.rc -O coff -o picture.res`
(Файл picture.png находится в одной папке с res.rc)
Потом компилирую `.exe`, включая его.

Могу ли я как-то к нему обратиться в коде `.exe` с помощью **ifstream**?

Comment: Да, можно открыть .exe файл и прочитать его содержимое, как и любой другой. Чтобы найти там ресурс придется его распарсить в соответствии ос спецификацией формата PE.

Comment: Ресурс – данные, входящие в сам исполняемый файл и загружается в оперативную память вместе с ним. Вы можете работать с этими данными с помощью специализированных системных функций. А ifsream здесь не нужен, так как исполняемый файл не является одновременно каталогом.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин В память ресурсы загружаются не вместе с исполняемым файлом, а, так сказать, "по требованию",  помощью вызовов специальных функций.

Comment: А что это вам даст? Вы же все равно будете читать файл в память? Это не какая-то XY-проблема? Что именно вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: А нафига его читать в память? Он УЖЕ ЗАГРУЖЕН.

Comment: Херри, покажите минимальный код, демонстрирующий два разных ресурса одного и того же файла на пересекающихся адресах. Или имеется ввиду, что система фактически подгружает фаил по частям и сама решает, какую часть когда загрузить? Так это и на код распространяется и на код. Долго не используемая функция может ждать вызова, а кисть или курсор загрузиться неявно. С точки зрения прикладного кода фаил загружен весь.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин Вы утверждаете, что во время работы приложения (*В память ресурсы загружаются не вместе с исполняемым файлом*) ресурсы **уже** находятся в памяти, независимо от того, вызывались ли функции для их загрузки или нет. Мне же вы возражаете, как если бы я утверждал, что ресурс можно загрузить, выгрузить и загрузить новый на то же место. При чем одно к другому - могут понять не только лишь все, а только вы...

Comment: @ТарасАтавин Ну, тогда подучитесь немого. Например, правилам вежливости — писать имя как положено, при адресном ответе использовать @ с именем. Русскому языку. А там постепенно придет и понимание программирования...

Comment: Серьёзно? Это я, оказывается, смею врать, отказываться аргументировать своё враньё, да ещё и приписывать свой брад? В отличие как раз от тебя. Где у меня хоть слово о физическом нахождении? А вот ты так и не смог опровергнуть тот факт, что логически все ресурсы уже числятся в оперативной памяти, выделенной процессу, и уже имеют там адреса.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл способ получить байты файла ресурса:

```cpp
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    HRSRC resInfo = FindResourceW(module, resName /*Имя ресурса*/, RT_RCDATA);
    if (resInfo == nullptr) wcout << L"Error open res!" << endl;
    HGLOBAL resBytes = LoadResource(module, resInfo);

    LPVOID lock = LockResource(resBytes);
    DWORD size = SizeofResource(module, resInfo);

    vector<BYTE> bytes(size);
    memcpy(bytes.data(), lock, size);

    ofstream out;
    out.open(fileName, ios::binary);

    unsigned __int64 ii = 0;
    unsigned __int64 &i = ii;

    while (i < size(data)) {
        out << data[i];
        i++;
    }
    out.close();
```

Comment: Повторюсь за @Mikhailo — ЗАЧЕМ? Вы просто записали память на диск в файл (да еще и через промежуточную память зачем-то и через странный в данном контексте оператор `<<`), но отнюдь не обратились к загруженному ресурсу как к файлу в памяти.

Comment: @Harry Бывают ситуации, когда удобнее хранить доп. фалы программы в самом exe. При надобности доставать их во внешний файл, а потом так-же при надобности удалять.

Особенно, если программа небольшая.

Причём, здесь я показал пример получения байтов файла, необязательно записывать их на диск.

И что плохого в `<<`?

Comment: Для этого можно обойтись малой кровью, совсем не нужно весь файл (особенно если большой) в память грузить. Во времена DOS, когда о ресурсах еще и речи не было, такое делалось проще. Маркер для поиска с размером, сам файл, все это через `copy/b` пришивалось к .exe-файлу. Потом просто поиск маркера, и простейшее копирование из файла в файл, и в память большой буфер тянуть незачем. Просто, незатейливо, без лишней памяти. А с `<<`... этот оператор медленнее побайтовой записи, а уж `write` целым блоком — и быстрее, и проще...

Comment: Херри, покажите минимальный код, демонстрирующий два разных ресурса одного и того же файла на пересекающихся адресах. Или имеется ввиду, что система фактически подгружает фаил по частям и сама решает, какую часть когда загрузить? Так это и на код распространяется и на код.